# MatterJS + Mattter Attractor Plugin: Attract only certain bodies

Tags: physics, collision, interaction, matter.js

I have built a very basic interactive sketch based on [MatterJS](https://brm.io/matter-js/) and its [plugin](https://github.com/liabru/matter-attractors) written by liabru. The idea is to choose the parent red bubble and three blue children by clicking on any on canvas.

[image]

The outcome should be like that

[image]

So, eventually, children should sneak through grey neighbors and stick to parent one.

The current snippet doesn't work right-sometimes children don't want to attract, sometimes they stuck behind other grey bubbles.

I have even tried to set active bubbles as heavy bodies, while grey as light, but didn't have any reasonable success.

The red bubble becomes static (`isStatic = true`), state is not null, on click, while children get property state not null at

```
Events.on(mouseConstraint, "mousedown", (event) => { 
    
    if(mouseConstraint.body) { 
    
        if(chain.length < 1){
            
            chain.push(mouseConstraint.body.label);
            mouseConstraint.body.render.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
            mouseConstraint.body.isStatic = true;
            mouseConstraint.body.state = "parent";

            mouseConstraint.body.pset to `childlugin = {
                  attractors: [
                    function(bodyA, bodyB) {
                        
                        if(bodyA.state != null && bodyB.state != null){

                            var force = {
                              x: (bodyA.position.x - bodyB.position.x) * 1e-5,
                              y: (bodyA.position.y - bodyB.position.y) * 1e-5,
                            };

                            // apply force to both bodies
                            Matter.Body.applyForce(bodyA, bodyA.position, Matter.Vector.neg(force));
                            Matter.Body.applyForce(bodyB, bodyB.position, force);
                            
                        }
          
                    }
                  ]
                }
                        
        }
        else if(chain.length < 4 && mouseConstraint.body.label != chain[0]){
            
            chain.push(mouseConstraint.body.label);
            mouseConstraint.body.render.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
            mouseConstraint.body.state = "child";
            
        }
    
    }

});
```

Pretty sure that the problem lies in bodies settings (frictions, mass and etc.) and force strength.

```js
/*

    density: defines the density of the body (mass per unit area).
    friction: defines the friction of the body. The value is always positive and is in the range (0, 1). A value of 0 means that the body may slide indefinitely.
    frictionAir: defines the air friction of the body (air resistance). A value of 0 means the body will never slow as it moves through space.
    frictionStatic: defines the static friction of the body (in the Coulomb friction model). A value of 0 means the body will never 'stick' when it is nearly stationary and only dynamic friction is used. 
    inertia: automatically calculated when vertices, mass or density are set or set through 
    inverseInertia: -
    inverseMass: -
    mass: defines the mass of the body
    motion: calculated during engine update only when sleeping is enabled.
    restitution: defines the restitution (elasticity) of the body
    
    */
    
    let attractiveBody = null;
    
    let config = {
        
        width: 800,
        height: 800,
        nodes: {min: 32, max: 64}
        
    };

    const Engine = Matter.Engine;
    const Render = Matter.Render;
    const World = Matter.World;
    const Bodies = Matter.Bodies;
    const Events = Matter.Events;
    const Runner = Matter.Runner;
    const MouseConstraint = Matter.MouseConstraint;
    const Mouse = Matter.Mouse;
    
    Matter.use("matter-attractors")
    
    const engine = Engine.create(), world = engine.world;
    engine.world.gravity.y = 0.0;

    let chain = [];
    
    World.add(engine.world, [
    
        // walls
        Bodies.rectangle(config.width / 2, 0, config.width, 20, { isStatic: true, render: {visible: false } }),
        Bodies.rectangle(config.width / 2, config.height, config.width, 20, { isStatic: true, render: {visible: false } } ),
        Bodies.rectangle(0, config.height / 2, 20, config.height, { isStatic: true, render: {visible: false } }),
        Bodies.rectangle(config.width, config.height / 2, 20, config.height, { isStatic: true, render: {visible: false } } ),
        
    ]);
    
    
    let N = 32, data;
    
    for(let i = 0; i < N; i++) { 

        const node = Bodies.circle(config.width / 2, config.height / 2, 32 + Math.random() * 32, {

          state: null,
          label: i,
          render: { fillStyle: "#DEDEDE" }

        });
        
        World.add(engine.world, node);

    }
    
    const render = Render.create({
    
    element: document.body,
    engine: engine,
    options: {
    width: config.width,
    height: config.height,
    wireframes: false,
    background: '#FFFFFF'

    }});
    
    let mouse = Mouse.create(render.canvas),
    mouseConstraint = MouseConstraint.create(engine, { mouse: mouse, constraint: { stiffness: 0.2 }});
        
World.add(engine.world, mouseConstraint);

Runner.run(engine);
Render.run(render);
    
Events.on(mouseConstraint, "mousedown", (event) => { 
    
    if(mouseConstraint.body) { 
    
        if(chain.length < 1){
            
            chain.push(mouseConstraint.body.label);
            mouseConstraint.body.render.fillStyle = "#FF0000";
            mouseConstraint.body.isStatic = true;
            mouseConstraint.body.state = "parent";
            
            //mouseConstraint.body.density = 1.0;

           let tmpComposite = Matter.Composite.create();
        
            Matter.Composite.move(engine.world, mouseConstraint.body, tmpComposite);
                             
            for(let i = 0; i < Number(mouseConstraint.body.label) - 1; i++ ) { Matter.Composite.move(engine.world, Matter.Composite.allBodies(engine.world), tmpComposite); }
        
            Matter.Composite.move(tmpComposite, Matter.Composite.allBodies(tmpComposite), engine.world);

            mouseConstraint.body.plugin = {
                  attractors: [
                    function(bodyA, bodyB) {
                        
                        if(bodyA.state != null && bodyB.state != null){

                            var force = {
                              x: (bodyA.position.x - bodyB.position.x) * 1e-4,
                              y: (bodyA.position.y - bodyB.position.y) * 1e-4,
                            };

                            // apply force to both bodies
                            Matter.Body.applyForce(bodyA, bodyA.position, Matter.Vector.neg(force));
                            Matter.Body.applyForce(bodyB, bodyB.position, force);
                            
                        }
          
                    }
                  ]
                }
                        
        }
        else if(chain.length < 4 && mouseConstraint.body.label != chain[0]){
            
            chain.push(mouseConstraint.body.label);
            mouseConstraint.body.render.fillStyle = "#0000FF";
            mouseConstraint.body.state = "child";
            //mouseConstraint.body.friction = 0.8;
            //mouseConstraint.body.frictionAir = 0.9;
            //mouseConstraint.body.frictionStatic = 0.1;
            
            let iterations = 0, r1 = 0, r2 = 0, dist = 10000;
            
        }
    
    }

});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/matter-js/0.19.0/matter.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/matter-attractors@0.1.6/build/matter-attractors.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have found an issue. I.e, the parent node is 17 and at function(bodyA, bodyB) { ... } checks pairs starting with 18, 19, 20 and etc., skipping first 17 nodes. 

If you manually moves node 17 body to the beginning in world.bodies array it doesn't help.